# Bash script: get folder size through FTP

Tags: bash, curl, ftp, directory, wget

I searched a lot and googled a lot too but I didn't find anything...

I'm using bash on linux...

I have to download a certain folder from a ftp server (i know ftp is deprecated, can't use ftps or sftp right now btw i'm in a local network).

I want to do a sort of integrity check of the downloaded folder, which has a lot of subfolders and files, so i choose to compare folder size as a test.

I'm downloading through wget but my question is...how can I check the folder size BEFORE downloading it so that i can store the size in a file and then compare with the downloaded one? In ftp, so...

I tried with a simply curl to the parent directory but there is no size information there...

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: thnx to Vitaliy! ended up doing
mkdir /root/fs
curlftpfs ftp://USER:PASSWORD@HOST/ /root/fs
du -ksh /root/fs/FOLDER | awk 'BEGIN{FS=" "} {print $1}'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't check folder size via protocol FTP. Try to connect remote folder on the main server via [curlftpfs](http://curlftpfs.sourceforge.net/) (if it possible).

Comment: is it possible to use this in a script? need to do that automatically..without interaction

Answer (score 1):

`wget` will recursively download all directory content one at a time. There's no way to determine the size of an entire directory using ftp. Though it's possible using ssh.

I recommend installing ssh server on your machine and after gaining an access, you can use the following command to get the size of the desired directory:

```
du -h desired_directory | tail -n 1
```

I do not recommend this method though, it's more reliable to get the hash checksum of the remote content and compare them with your downloaded content. It's far more reliable and it's already used by many download clients to check the integrity of the files.

Comment: need to be automatic, that's the problem, and more ssh on that server is not possible 'cause it has a strange way of connecting via ssh, it's behind a cloud environment

Comment: It's actually possible to automate ssh and ftp sessions using something like "Expect" .What exactly do you mean by a "cloud environment" and "strange way"?

Comment: I mean that in that cloud environment you access to a frontend ssh server and then it redirects you to the specific environment you want (manual choose) spawning a new shell too..

Answer (score 1):

It basically depends on what your `ftp` client and your `ftp` server can do. With some I know, the default `ls` does the job and they even have a `size` command:

```
ftp> help size
size           show size of remote file
ftp> size foo
213 305
ftp> ls foo
200 PORT command successful.
150 Opening ASCII mode data connection for file list
-rw-r--r--   1 foo bar      305 Aug  1  2013 foo
226 Transfer complete.
```